# Custom admin dashboard displaying specific model instances

Tags: django, admin, dashboard, mezzanine, django-grappelli

I'm creating a website with Django (+ django-grappelli + mezzanine) and I would like to customize my **Admin panel to add a new dashboard** displaying specific model instances.

Let's say that I have a model :

```
class Thing(models.Model):
    published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

And several model instances (for example T1, T2, T3 where T1 and T2 are published but not T3) and I would like to have a dashboard **displaying a list** of all "Thing" instances that are not published (in this case, T3).

Any ideas? Thanks for reading !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I've found a solution. Here are the guidelines :

Mezzanine allows the users to customize their dashboard giving a function and registering it as **inclusion tag**.

Documentation : http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/admin-customization.html -> Dashboard https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags

To implement such a function, you need to follow these steps :

1) Add a **templatetags folder** in your application (don't forget the **__init__.py** file) and create a file called "your_tags.py" inside of this package.

2) In this new file, add a function to provide data to the new dashboard you want to add in the Dashboard panel. It could look like this :

```
from mezzanine import template
from your_app.models import Thing

register = template.Library()
@register.inclusion_tag('unpublished_things.html')
def show_unpublished_things():
    plugins = Thing.objects.filter(published=False)
    return {'things':things}
```

3) Then you need to create the "unpublished_things.html" file used in the inclusion tag, so for example create such a file in the **templates folder** of your application. The file could look like this (assuming there is a "get_admin_url" function in the Thing model) :

```
{% load i18n %}

<div class="group-collapsible">
    <div class="module">
    <table>
        <caption>Unpublished things</caption>
        {% for thing in things %}
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" width="100%"><a
                    href="{{ thing.get_admin_url }}">{{ thing.name }}</a></th>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

4) To finish, you just need to add the following in your **local_settings.py** (or settings.py) :

```
DASHBOARD_TAGS = (
    ("your_tags.show_unpublished_things", "mezzanine_tags.app_list"),
    ("comment_tags.recent_comments",),
    ("mezzanine_tags.recent_actions",),
)
```

This configuration will automatically add the generated stuff provided by the function "show_unpublished_things" at the top of the first row, in the Dashboard of your admin panel.

**Don't forget to restart your server if you get an error !**

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is a ModelAdmin with a custom list_filter, as seen here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter

For example, in the same folder as your models.py, you would create an admin.py which looked something like:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Thing


class ThingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ('published',)

admin.site.register(Thing, ThingAdmin)
```

This will give you a new section in your admin site for your Thing objects, and allow you to filter them by whether or not they have been published.

Comment: That looks great! I'll try this solution and keep you in touch :)

Comment: Ok that wasn't what I was looking for. Have a look at my reply to have the solution.